# Jscrollpane not working on ipad for me

Tags: ipad, jscrollpane

Ive used a jscrollpane here and its working fine on normal computers: 
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppr6/aw11

However unlike the demoes here, its not working on an ipad: 
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I didnt realize a new version had just come out. Updating it fixed this.